# How to install memcached with php 7.1 in centOS?

Tags: php, memcached

I've tried following commands:

- `sudo yum -y update`
- `sudo yum install -y libevent libevent-devel`
- `sudo yum install -y memcached`
- `sudo yum install -y php-pecl-memcache`
- `sudo service memcached restart`
- `sudo service httpd restart`

I can see only memcache module which is installed after run above commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Finally got Solution!**
I've done some research on installation any module for php 7.1. I got success while run below command:

- `sudo yum install -y php71-memcached` [use 72 instead of 71(php version) for php7.2]

Answer (score 2):

I think you had tried commands from this link, but all are not working :D
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/memcache/memcache_centos.html